# How to cancel an event listening after repeating the event?

Tags: javascript

I've created an app trying to learn keydown event listeners. When I press arrow keys, divs' background color changes. However, I'd like to know how to cancel the effect, ie. return to the default background color, when I press the same key again.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", pressKeyOn);
const arUp = document.querySelector(".ar-up");
const arLeft = document.querySelector(".ar-left");
const arRight = document.querySelector(".ar-right");

const arDown = document.querySelector(".ar-down");

function pressKeyOn(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    arUp.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    arDown.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    arRight.style.backgroundColor = "navy";
  } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    arLeft.style.backgroundColor = "violet";
  }
}
```

So how to return to the original (eg. yellow background), if I press respective arrow key?

Comment: You could track what is the last pressed key.

Comment: classList.toggle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class for all the colors and toggle it on every click.

```js
const arUp = document.querySelector(".ar-up");
const arLeft = document.querySelector(".ar-left");
const arRight = document.querySelector(".ar-right");
const arDown = document.querySelector(".ar-down");

function pressKeyOn(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 38) arUp.classList.toggle("red")
  else if (e.keyCode === 40) arDown.classList.toggle("green")
  else if (e.keyCode === 39) arRight.classList.toggle("navy")
  else if (e.keyCode === 37) arLeft.classList.toggle("violet")
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", pressKeyOn);
```

```css
.red{ background-color: red;}
.green{ background-color: green;}
.navy{ background-color: navy;}
.violet{ background-color: violet;}
```

```html
<div class="ar-up">ar-up</div>
<div class="ar-left">ar-left</div>
<div class="ar-right">ar-right</div>
<div class="ar-down">ar-down</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't thought about it.  In fact, I haven't tested toggle class with keydown events. But I'm not very experienced yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more generic version using classList.toggle

```js
const colors = {
  "ArrowUp": "red",
  "ArrowDown": "green",
  "ArrowLeft": "navy",
  "ArrowRight": "violet"
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    const key = e.key;
    if (colors[key]) document
      .querySelector(`.${key}`)
      .classList
      .toggle(colors[key])
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.navy {
  background-color: navy;
}

.violet {
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="ArrowUp">ar-up</div>
<div class="ArrowLeft">ar-left</div>
<div class="ArrowRight">ar-right</div>
<div class="ArrowDown">ar-down</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mplungjan. Your solution is more sophisticated. So far I'm not experienced enough to think it up myself. However, I understand your code.

Comment: So I already commented to use classList.toggle before the other answer